# oracle mariaDB installation on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, oracle, mariadb

How to install oracle mariaBD in ubuntu 14.04 ? please provide me step by step method

Comment: what do you mean by installing oracle ? do you mean to install java ?

Comment: Talk about confusion. Oracle *does not* have anything to do with MariaDB. The whole point of MariaDB was to free MySQL from Oracle.

Comment: @edwardtorvalds https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/faq/what-is-the-goal-of-mariadb/

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1: Add MariaDB Apt-get Repositories**

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0xcbcb082a1bb943db
```

**For Ubuntu 14.04 “trusty”**

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://ftp.kaist.ac.kr/mariadb/repo/5.5/ubuntu trusty main'
```

**For Ubuntu 12.04 LTS “precise”**

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://ftp.kaist.ac.kr/mariadb/repo/5.5/ubuntu precise main'
```

**Step 2: Install MariaDB in Ubuntu**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
```

*While installing MariaDB using above command installer will prompt for MariaDB root account password twice like below snapshot.*
[image: oracle mariadb account password]

**Step 3: Login To MariaDB**

*After completing installation you can connect to MariaDB using following command.*

```
mysql -u root -p
```

`Enter password:<enter password>`

[source](http://tecadmin.net/install-mariadb-5-5-in-ubuntu/)

Comment: You don't need to add a repository for 14.04. It's available in the official repositories: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&keywords=mariadb-client